# start Mongodb container as non root user

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using official mongodb docker  FROM mongo:3.2. In the entrypoint.sh I am restarting the Mongodb with replica mode. Mongodb process is owned by root user. Is there any way I can start the container by non root user and able to restart the mongodb in the replica set mode. Right now I am getting the following error.

2017-10-27T20:08:23.888+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating

My docker file is

```
FROM mongo:3.2
COPY entrypoint.sh /root/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/entrypoint.sh"] here
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `USER` command available in dockerfile, when using ENTRYPOINT, CMD, RUN instructions to start/execute the process with the required user.

Syntax:

`USER <user>[:<group>]` or 
`USER <UID>[:<GID>]`

Example:

```
FROM mongo:3.2
COPY entrypoint.sh /root/entrypoint.sh
USER deploy:root
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Update From `user2010672`: (working solution)

```
FROM mongo:3.2
COPY entrypoint.sh /root/entrypoint.sh
RUN chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log /data/db 
USER mongodb
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Thanks `user2010672`

Comment: If I start the container as non root user then I won't be able to restart mongod as it is owned by root user. In entrypoint.sh I am restarting mongod in replica set mode. mongo --eval "var res = rs.initiate({_id: 'indexers', members: [ {_id: 0, host: \"$(hostname):27017\"} ] }); printjson(res); if (res.ok == 0) { throw new Exception(res.errmsg); }"

Comment: starting the container using the mongodb user resolved the issue. I can start the container and restart the mongodb in entrypoint.sh in the replicaset mode using mongodb user which is non root user.    RUN chown -R mongodb:mongodb  /var/log
RUN chown -R mongodb /data/db USER mongodb

Comment: Hmm I tried @user2010672's example but I am hitting a: exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating

Any ideas how to get around this? I Already tried changing the permissions

Answer (score 6):

Using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    yourmongo:
        image: mongo:xenial
        container_name: yourmongo
        restart: always
        user: 1000:1000
        volumes:
            - ./yourmongo-folder:/data/db
```

`1000:1000` are the chosen values for uid:gid (user-id:group-id)

EDIT: don't forget to add the folder with the correct permissions: `mkdir yourmongo-folder && chown 1000:1000 yourmongo-folder` (This must be done on the Docker host machine BEFORE bringing up the Docker service).

Comment: Mongo container failed to start when I did that

Comment: Add the folder with the correct permissions before running `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

You can customize user on docker [run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command using the flag **--user** with **user:group** format